# Power Automate Date Comparison Returning False Even Though Values are Equal

Tags: conditional-statements, powerapps, power-automate

I am trying to figure out why my conditional equates to false for both items that get returned despite them being equal.

My conditional is as follows

```
formatDateTime(items('Apply_to_each')?['DueDateCalculated'],'yyyy-MM-dd') is equal to

formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),54),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

As you can see in the picture attached the values are equal and in the correct format but it results in a false. I am out of ideas other than setting those both to variables.

[image]

Comment: Throw a `string()` expression around the two values and see if that helps in the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The values are not equal because there is a hidden **hh:mm:ss.SSS** component inside each date variable, which you don't take into account.

It is not really obvious from the screenshot provided what values you are comparing with one another, but `addDays(utcNow(),54)` just can't be equal to `['DueDateCalculated']`, because at least one of them has **hh:mm:ss.SSS** component in it.

Comment: So even though I use the format date on both it still has the hidden time items? I am comparing the two expressions they are not set to variables. Which could be the issue.